# puppeteer - Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector'

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer, eval

I'm trying to select some nested divs using puppeteer `$$eval`. I've copied the XPath of the DOm elements I need to select but seems not working.

```js
    //XPath //*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a/span
    await page.waitForSelector('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a/span')
    const names = await page.$$eval('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a/span', (el) => {
        return el.map( n => n.innerHTML )
    })
    citiesList.push(names)

    //XPath //*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a
    await page.waitForSelector('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a')
    const href = await page.$$eval('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a', (el) => {
        return el.map( a => a.getAttribute('href') )
    })
    citiesLinks.push(href)
```

With this code I will get always this error

```js
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a/span' is not a valid selector
```

How I can use xpath with `$$eval` correctly?

Comment: The word "selector" refers to a CSS selector, not an XPath. `$$eval` expects a CSS selector. Use `page.$x` or `page.waitForXPath` to use XPath. As an aside, I'm not a big fan of these hyper-precise browser-generated selelctors and paths. They seem really brittle -- if a single thing changes in the HTML tree, which happens constantly in most real web apps as elements are added and removed with JS dynamically, the whole thing breaks. Much better is to use a direct class or id. But without seeing the page you're working with or the desired result, I can't offer much more than that.

Comment: @ggorlen I've opted for using a CSS selector. I was trying to use the `$$eval()` funtion in a wrong way and with the wrong CSS selector. I've corrected by targeting directly the parent DOM element of the tag I was looking for and I've solved the problem

Comment: Great. Consider adding a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Which puppeteer version is you are using? It depends on version based problem. I have same trouble on puppeteer@14.3.0. I resolved with this link: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3241

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by targeting directly the DOM elements I need.
In my case I have an `li` tag with `.list-item` bootstrap class.

```js
 await page.waitForSelector('li.list-item > a', (el) => {
   return el.map( a => a.getAttribute('href') )
 })
 citiesLinks.push(href)
```